# Accessing private fields of a Java

Tags: java, imageview, private-members

javax.swing.text.html.ImageView;
lines 111 and 258-267
http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/javax/swing/text/html/ImageView.java.html

```
public class ImageView extends View {
    ....
    private float vAlign;
    ....
}
```

My program:

```
.....
ImageView layeredPane = (ImageView) view;
Field privateStringField = layeredPane.getClass().getDeclaredField("vAlign");
privateStringField.setAccessible(true);
layeredPane.vAlign = 2.0;
.....
```

I get:

> Test.java:80: error: vAlign has private access in ImageView
>   layeredPane.vAlign = 2.0;

How do I fix it? I need to put a value of 2.0

Answer (score 6):

You fix it by not trying to get at private implementation details. Basically you shouldn't be doing this. Your code will end up being brittle even when you're still using this version of `ImageView`, and vulnerable to changes between versions. The whole point of it being private is to *stop* you from accessing it directly.

You *can* fall `privateStringField.setFloat(layeredPane, 2.0f)` but I would *strongly* advise against it.

(It's odd to call it `privateStringField` when it's a *float* field, by the way...)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class can not access a member of class javax.swing.text.html.ImageView with modifiers "private" I understand that it is bad, but it is very necessary to make. Perhaps there is a way to add my own method, or modify protected void setPropertiesFromAttributes?

Comment: @user1221483: Are you getting that *after* calling `setAccessible(true)`? I'm not convinced that it *is* necessary - it really feels like something you should try to achieve in a different way, via more layout.

Comment: pardon, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set float field javax.swing.text.html.ImageView.vAlign to (double)0.5 .  I use privateStringField.setFloat(layeredPane, (float)0.75); No errors and it does not work :'(

Comment: @user1221483: Oops, just saw the `2.0` (which is a `double`, not a `float`) and assumed it was a `double` field. So yes, if `setFloat` doesn't throw any exceptions then it *is* working, in terms of setting the field. That it doesn't have the desired effect just goes along with what I've been saying all along: **it's a bad idea to do this**. It's a private field, so code in the class may well be making assumptions about what values it can hold, and when it can change. It's private for a reason, so find a way of achieving your aim *without* working against the framework.

Answer (score 3):

First off, why would you want to use 2.0? I thought that the vAlign uses the [java.awt.Component contants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT) for BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT, CENTER_ALIGNMENT AND TOP_ALIGNMENT which hold 1.0f, 0.5f, and 0.0f respectively, and so a value of 2.0 may not make much sense.

Regardless, since it's a private field, don't fiddle with it directly and change it via appropriate means. It appears that this private field is set via attributes:

```
Object alignment = attr.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.ALIGN);
```

Comment: I made a mistake, should the value of 0.75.

Comment: @user1221483: But why? What does 0.75 mean? There are only three vertical HTML image tag align attributes: top, middle and bottom, that's it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels HALFWAY_BETWEEN_MIDDLE_AND_BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT :)

Comment: http://s40.radikal.ru/i090/1202/6b/a70ead9a5661.gif I really need to do is 0.75 I have 3 days trying to do it. Help please. Can I do this by replacing the native ImageView.class in my ImageView.class?

Comment: @user1221483: Heck if you really must mess with this class you could extend it and override the `public float getAlignment(int axis) {` method to return what you want if the parameter is `View.Y_AXIS` and return the `super.getAlignment(axis)` result otherwise. But I still think that this is dangerous and ill-conceived.